# Compare a map object and its reference C++

Tags: c++, reference, stdmap

I have the following maps

```
map<int,string> m1;
map<int,string> m2;
call(m1);
call(m2);

template<typename T>
void call(T &m)
{
  // Compare if m == m1
  How to do?
}
```

I need to know which of `m1` and `m2` is being called in the current function at run time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to check it based on the contents of map, you can use [`operator==`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_cmp):

```
template<typename T>
void call(T &m)
{
  if (m == m1)
    ...
}
```

If you want to identify whether they're the same instance, since the parameter is passed by reference, you can compare their addresses:

```
template<typename T>
void call(T &m)
{
  if (&m == &m1)
    ...
}
```

As @Smeeheey pointed, you need to consider about how to provide the compared object (i.e. `m1` or its address) inside the template function, and it's not clear from your snippets.

Comment: The first answer will likely cause a compiler error if the `call` function is ever called with a parameter of some other type (which I presume it must be somewhere, otherwise there would be no point declaring it as a template function)

Comment: Yes, I was looking for the second answer :)

Comment: @Smeeheey Yes. I have the same question about that.

Answer (score 1):

To improve on the accepted answer, if you want to avoid compiler errors due to the function `call` being called on types other than `map<int, string>`, you need a template helper function:

```
template <typename T, typename U>
bool is_equal(const T& t, const U& u)
{
    return false;
}

template <typename T>
bool is_equal(T& t, T& u)
{
    return &t == &u;
}

template<typename T>
void call(T &m)
{
  // Compare if m == m1
  if(is_equal(m, m1))
    std::cout << "Yes";
  else
    std::cout << "No";
}
```

Comment: Instead , how about something like this.

template<typename T>
void call(T &m)
{
  if ((void*)&m == (void*)&m1)
    ...
}